# Replace Character Elements in vector with Numbers in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, vector, character

I have a vector from a data frame which contains string/character elements, and I would like to replace these string/character elements with numbers based on whether they contain a certain group of characters, and I was wondering how I could go about doing that. For example, lets say I have a column from a data frame with string elements as follows:

```
df$Stringvector <- c("aaca", "bbb", "edee", "ca bb" "ttt t", "ui de", "k jkl")
```

Now, what I would like to do is replace the elements of the vector with a `1` if the elements have the character combination `ca` or `de`, and replace the elements with `2` if they do not contain either of these combinations. Since the 1st, 3rd, 4th, and 6th elements in `df$Stringvector` have `ca` and `de` in their strings these get replaced by `1`, while all others get replaced by `2` so that we now get:

```
df$Stringvector <- c(1,2,1,1,2,1,2)
```

What's a good way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Does a combination of `ca` include `ca` and `ac`? - i.e. - in any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the pattern using `grepl`.

```
> as.numeric(!grepl("ca|de", x)) + 1
[1] 1 2 1 1 2 1 2
```